# The app references non-public selectors in Payload

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, non-public-selectors

I just tried to submit an app to the app store and we have received the following message when trying to upload the binary:

"The app references non-public selectors in Payload ..............."

How am I supposed to debug this. I have various libraries included in the project and compiling the project does not give any warnings at all. Surely there is a way to figure out what particular library/function call has caused this.

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of an old post, so I'm not sure if you still need an answer. If you're confident you're not using private APIs in your code, I'm not sure how you'd find it in third party libraries. I'd suggest contacting the App review board and asking them.

Comment: Google Analytics can involves this warning. But it is allowed be integrated in the app.

Comment: I am using Facebook plugins in my app so what to do next?