# App Submission Warning: "The app references non-public selectors in My_application.app/My_application: productName"

Tags: iphone, ios6, app-store-connect

I have recently tried to submit an iOS app to the Apple Store and it triggered the following warning:

"The app references non-public selectors in My_application.app/My_application: productName"

I have seen prior questions asked in stackoverflow in these links but there has not been any concrete answers to whether or not this causes the app to be rejected.
[iTune, App upload warning. App references non-public selectors in : productName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798537/itune-app-upload-warning-app-references-non-public-selectors-in-productname)
[The app references non-public selectors in Payload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10023343/the-app-references-non-public-selectors-in-payload)

In my app, I have built it using Cocos2D 2.0 and Chartboost 3.1.1, FacebookSDK 3.1.1.
There has not been any additional 3rd party APIs integrated into the app.

Has anyone encounter a similar problem using the above mentioned SDKs?
Has anyone had their app rejected because of the warning above?

Please share your experiences so I might be able to rectify this problem within my app.
Thanks so much.

Comment: hey! did you get to the bottom of this error? i am having the same problem. :(

Answer (score 0):

Just submit it to app store, it working for me 3 times. The problem sometimes happens when Apple has changed for new iOS version.